# How to update or insert array object in array MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

update or insert object :

```
{
"Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
"TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
"HS" : NumberInt(9),
"AS" : NumberInt(9)
},
```

I want to update Results array element if is exist Id=1190001 and TypeNo = 2 else insert new element into array which Id=1190001 and TypeNo = 2.

There may be more than one document belonging to this Results array. All documents must be affected.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64ba3c55b9e000058c561224"),
    "FData" : {
        //otherproperties,
        "IC" : {
            //otherproperties,
            "iEv" : [
                {
                    //otherproperties,
                    "nev" : NumberInt(1169644),
                    "Results" : [
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1169644),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(3),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(0)
                        },
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1169644),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(1),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(3),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(0)
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    //otherproperties,
                    "nev" : NumberInt(1190001),
                    "Results" : [
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(1),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(0),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(1)
                        },
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(1),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(1)
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
"Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
"TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
"HS" : NumberInt(9),
"AS" : NumberInt(9)
},
```

Condition 1 expected result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64ba3c55b9e000058c561224"),
    "FData" : {
        //otherproperties,
        "IC" : {
            //otherproperties,
            "iEv" : [
                {
                    //otherproperties,
                    "nev" : NumberInt(1169644),
                    "Results" : [
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1169644),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(3),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(0)
                        },
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1169644),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(1),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(3),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(0)
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    //otherproperties,
                    "nev" : NumberInt(1190001),
                    "Results" : [
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(1),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(0),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(1)
                        },
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(9), //modified
                            "AS" : NumberInt(9)  //modified
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

update or insert object :

```
{
"Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
"TypeNo" : NumberInt(3),
"HS" : NumberInt(11),
"AS" : NumberInt(11)
},
```

Condition 2 expected result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64ba3c55b9e000058c561224"),
    "FData" : {
        //otherproperties,
        "IC" : {
            //otherproperties,
            "iEv" : [
                {
                    //otherproperties,
                    "nev" : NumberInt(1169644),
                    "Results" : [
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1169644),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(3),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(0)
                        },
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1169644),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(1),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(3),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(0)
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    //otherproperties,
                    "nev" : NumberInt(1190001),
                    "Results" : [
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(1),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(0),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(1)
                        },
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(2),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "AS" : NumberInt(1)  
                        },
                         //Inserted new element
                        {
                            "Id" : NumberInt(1190001),
                            "TypeNo" : NumberInt(3),
                            "HS" : NumberInt(11),
                            "AS" : NumberInt(11)
                        },
                         //Inserted new element
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```